# php on command line display empty

Tags: php, command-line, centos, centos7

php on command line display empty

I can't get result on command line with php

Like this↓

```
$ php -r "phpinfo();"
$ php
```

Comment: whats your question ?

Comment: And what exactly does your command line do when you call php -r "phpinfo();"?

Comment: could you please try: `whereis php`? and then, if there is a match, try: `php -a` then `phpinfo();` and exit the input, as it is described here in Stackoverflow documentation: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/php/189/getting-started-with-php/17980/php-cli

Comment: I don't know if you'll get anything meaningful but you can get last exit code by running `echo $?` afterwards.

Comment: I got
$ whereis php
php: /usr/bin/php /usr/lib64/php /etc/php.d /etc/php.ini /usr/share/php /usr/share/man/man1/php.1.gz
$ php -a
$ echo $?
0